# in the example below how possible is to rotate the nurbspath on its own z axis?

Tags: bezier-curves

it is a nurbspath that i am using to control this skeleton, but i am unable to rotate. i can only move sideways forward and backwards but i cannot rotate. is that possible? i am new to blender.[image: desired rotation]

[image: control points shown]

[image]

Comment: Are transformations locked in said object? Could you post more info about your scene and objects, share an **as simplified as possible** [file showing the issue](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com). As it stands it is hard to understand what is going on.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4350" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4350/)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping...any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I entirely understand you issue. Assuming this is what you want to do.

In *Object Mode* select your curve and place the 3D cursor at its origin with the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> menu.

Enter *Edit Mode* and select one or all of the vertex at the end of the curve.

Change transform pivot to the *3D cursor* with <kbd>.</kbd> Period key.

You can then rotate the selected vertex. For a smooth transformation like below try using *Proportional Edit*.

[image]